# How can I append a draggable div to a different div when dropped over a different div?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to drag and drop an icon from a menu onto a div on the page and then append it not to the div it was dropped over but to a separate div.

For example, I want to be able to able to drag the icon out of the menu, drop it over the div "dropover_target" to that it can pick up part of it's class but ultimately append the icon to the div "actual_target".

I envisage the html would start like this:

```
<div id="menu">
<div id="icon" class="none"></div>
</div>

<div id="dropover_target" class="area"></div>

<div id="actual_target"></div>
```

But end up like this:

```
<div id="menu"></div>

<div id="dropover_target"></div>

<div id="actual_target">
<div id="icon" class="area+stuff"></div>
</div>
```

I have successfully used the following jQuery to get the class of the dropover_target div and set it as the class for the icon. But I cannot then append the icon div to the actual_target div.

```
 function dragDrop(ev) { 
    ev.preventDefault(); 
    var icon = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text"); 
    var area = 'pos-' + ev.target.id; //get the id of the dropover_target
    $('#'+icon).addClass(area); //add a new class to the icon 

    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(token)); 
//this line appends the icon to the dropover_target - which is not what I want to do!

    $('#actual_target').appendChild(document.getElementById(token)); 
//this line is to append the icon to the actual target - but does not seem to want to work!
}
```

Comment: you are mixing vanilla JavaScript and JQuery. appendChild is not a JQuery method.

Comment: Thanks - it turns out changing appendChild() to append() solved the problem $('#actual_target').append(document.getElementById(token));